# Overflow text in flexbox autosize container

Tags: html, css, pug, flexbox

I am using `FlexBox` for an app, and I want to crop text in `.text` with `flex-grow: 1`

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/LestaD/pen/ZOpBzM)

Jade layout:

```
  main
    aside
    content
      section Hello
      footer
        .panel
          .avatar
          .text
            div Vestibulum ullamcorper mauris at ligula Suspendisse non nisl sit amet Donec mi odio faucibus at Vestibulum ullamcorper mauris at ligula Suspendisse non nisl sit amet Donec mi odio faucibus at Vestibulum ullamcorper mauris at ligula Suspendisse non nisl sit amet Donec mi odio faucibus at
          .actions
            .act
            .act
            .act
```

Comment: I want like this:


`[[  ][ lorem ipsum dolos rolese...][[  ][  ][  ]]]`

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more? How do you want the `.text` div to behave?

Comment: I want do footer max width(available width - `section` width).
In `footer .panel`   set `.avatar` and `.actions` fixed width.
But `.text` must be max width of available space, no more.
And crop text in `.text` with ellipsis

Comment: I need CSS solution

Comment: @LestaD Please **edit your question** with further details - they don't belong in comments. This becomes very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular JavaScript to slice a given string in JADE by prefixing a new line with `-`. For example `- var myVar = 'contains a string'.slice(0,5)`

In your case you can change your JADE-Code like this, [here is the PEN](http://codepen.io/pure180/pen/yJbAxL)

```
.panel
  .avatar
  .text
  - var divContent = 'Vestibulum ullamcorper mauris at ligula Suspendisse non nisl sit amet Donec mi odio faucibus at Vestibulum ullamcorper mauris at ligula Suspendisse non nisl sit amet Donec mi odio faucibus at Vestibulum ullamcorper mauris at ligula Suspendisse non nisl sit amet Donec mi odio faucibus at'
  div.notTruncated= divContent 
  - var divContentTruncated = divContent.slice(0,180)
  div.truncated= divContentTruncated + '...'
```

**CSS-Solution**

First of all you need to wrap your text with a `block` or an `inline-block` element. If you are using an `inline` element it doesn't work, except you change the element behavior with css. If you want to read something about css nowrap and ellipses, [go to this page](https://davidwalsh.name/css-ellipsis).

This would be the CSS for the element, [here is your PEN](http://codepen.io/pure180/pen/dXWLwk)

```
.truncatedText {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:inline-block;   
}
```

Comment: But i don't know right count of symbols to slice. Because, i have mobile phone, tablets and desktop

Comment: You should say that you need a CSS solution... I'll edit my awnser to fit you question.